# MySQL copy multiple rows values with same ID into new columns?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
ItemID    |    File
```

---

```
1           /storage/somefile1.jpg
1           /storage/somefile2.jpg
1           /storage/somefile3.jpg
1           /storage/somefile5.jpg  

2           /storage/somerandomfile.jpg
2           /storage/anotherrandomfile.jpg
2           /storage/yetanotherrandomfile.jpg
2           /storage/somefile.jpg
```

I am wanting to create a new column for each file rather than having 1 row per file. Such as:

```
ItemID    |    File                     |    File2                        | File3 etc...
```

---

```
1           /storage/somefile1.jpg      |   /storage/somefile2.jpg        |   /storage/..


2           /storage/somerandomfile.jpg |  /storage/anotherrandomfile.jpg | /storage/..
```

Is there any way to automate this with a query?

Comment: I don't think so. AFAIK, you'll have to use some script to create the queries. What programming language are you using?

Comment: Your DB design looks optimal as is. Are you sure you want to change it? What exact problem are you trying to address?

Comment: I'm trying to prep the data for export into a CSV so I can import it into a different CMS. Having all the file values grouped together under 1 ID would just make it a lot easier to manage from a import perspective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After seeing your comment and that you're just trying to make a CSV out of it, you can do something like this:

```
<?php
$query = $db->query('SELECT ItemID, GROUP_CONCAT(File SEPARATOR \'|$|\') AS Files FROM Table GROUP BY ItemID');
// Use a string that cant appear as part of the filename as the separator
$fh = fopen('items.csv', 'w');
foreach ($query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row) {
    $files = explode('|$|', $row['Files']);
    fputcsv($fh, array_merge(array($row['ItemID']), $files));
}
fclose($fh);
```

Answer (score 0):

No. You can't do it(change mysql scheme) on fly.

Comment: If I manually created the new columns and columns File1 through File5 all ready existing would it be possible to iterate through each row with the same ID then copy the contents of the original column to each of the new empty columns?

Comment: Sure. But it  would be better to write script for populating these rows.

Answer (score 0):

Following my comment on the question, you can create a new table with your desired schema, and run something like that (assuming PDO):

```
<?php
$db->beginTransaction();
$query = $db->query('SELECT ItemID, GROUP_CONCAT(File SEPARATOR \'|$|\') AS Files FROM Table GROUP BY ItemID');
// Use a string that cant appear as part of the filename as the separator
$sth = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO NewTable (ItemID, File1, File2, File3) VALUES (:ItemID, :File1, :File2, :File3)');
foreach ($query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row) {
    $files = explode('|$|', $row['Files']);
    $sth->execute(array(
        'ItemID' => $row['ItemID'],
        'File1' => isset($files[0]) ? $files[0] : NULL,
        'File2' => isset($files[1]) ? $files[1] : NULL,
        'File3' => isset($files[2]) ? $files[2] : NULL,
    ));
}
$db->commit();
```

However, I do think your current schema design is better. Why are you trying to change it?

Comment: Just for prepping the data for CSV export so it can be imported into a different CMS having all of the files grouped under the 1 ID just makes that part of the process easier even though in the end it will end up in a similar schema. Maybe there is an easier way to just make a query that will make it "look" that way rather than moving the files into their own columns.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate your CSV right in SQL, you can use the following query as starting point:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(',', ItemID, GROUP_CONCAT(File ORDER BY File SEPARATOR ',')) AS FullCSVRow
FROM ItemToFile
GROUP BY ItemID
```

... which returns:

```
FullCSVRow
1,/storage/somefile1.jpg,/storage/somefile2.jpg,/storage/somefile3.jpg,/storage/somefile5.jpg
2,/storage/somerandomfile.jpg,/storage/somerandomfile.jpg,/storage/somerandomfile.jpg,/storage/somerandomfile.jpg
3,/storage/file-1-of-2.jpg,/storage/file-2-of-2.jpg
```

And if you are using PHP you have full control on what queries you do and how you build them. You don't need to change the DB design.

Comment: That's a smart way of doing that, but it could be problematic if any filename contains ',' in it, as it won't be properly escaped for usage in a CSV format

Comment: @shesek: ... and if there's an item that does not have 4 files exactly, as in my example. That's what I mean with "starting point" :) Whatever, I would do it in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
   ItemID,

   ( SELECT t2.File FROM ( SELECT @row := @row + 1 AS r, File FROM my_table AS t3
     JOIN ( SELECT @row := 0 ) AS init
     WHERE t1.ItemID = t3.ItemID ORDER BY t3.File ) AS t2 WHERE t2.r = 1 ),

   ( SELECT t2.File FROM ( SELECT @row := @row + 1 AS r, File FROM my_table AS t3
     JOIN ( SELECT @row := 0 ) AS init
     WHERE t1.ItemID = t3.ItemID ORDER BY t3.File ) AS t2 WHERE t2.r = 2 ),

   ( SELECT t2.File FROM ( SELECT @row := @row + 1 AS r, File FROM my_table AS t3
     JOIN ( SELECT @row := 0 ) AS init
     WHERE t1.ItemID = t3.ItemID ORDER BY t3.File ) AS t2 WHERE t2.r = 3 ),

   ( SELECT t2.File FROM ( SELECT @row := @row + 1 AS r, File FROM my_table AS t3
     JOIN ( SELECT @row := 0 ) AS init
     WHERE t1.ItemID = t3.ItemID ORDER BY t3.File ) AS t2 WHERE t2.r = 4 )

   FROM my_table AS t1
```