# Query with HAVING, can you explain this behavior?

Tags: mysql

Can you explain this behavior?

```
CREATE TABLE test( a INT );

INSERT INTO test VALUES (21), (22), (23), (24), (25);

SELECT @row := @row + 1 AS r, a FROM test
  JOIN ( SELECT @row := 0 ) AS init
  ORDER BY a;

----------
| r | a  |
----------
| 1 | 21 |
| 2 | 22 |
| 3 | 23 |
| 4 | 24 |
| 5 | 25 |
----------

SELECT @row := @row + 1 AS r, a FROM test
  JOIN ( SELECT @row := 0 ) AS init
  HAVING r = 3
  ORDER BY a;

----------
| r | a  |
----------
| 4 | 23 |
----------
```

Comment: It's almost the same situation: `select rand() r from something having r > 0.5`. You will not get the results as expected. HAVING clause does the calculation again. But it's interesting why MySQL does it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The evaluation of the `HAVING` clause is causing an initial calculation of `@row := @row + 1 AS r`:

```
1st Pass: r = 1, fail.
2nd Pass: r = 2, fail.
3rd Pass: r = 3, success.
```

Then when sending the results to the client `@row := @row + 1 AS r` is evaluated once more and value of @row becomes 4 so you get the result:

```
r = 4, a = 23.
```

Comment: This means the expressions in select are evaluated twice ?

Comment: In this scenario it would have to be, because r is calculated to find the join query, then it's added to when selected.

Comment: I don't see any `r + 1` in any of my queries. `r` is the alias for `@row := @row + 1`. Furthermore `@row + 1` is exactly the 1 based row number for each row, see the first query and its result.

Comment: @nobody HAVING clause evaluates the expression of `r` again before the comparison.

Comment: Indeed. The way I saw it in my head, it loops through, r = 1, no, r = 2, no, r = 3, Great we've satisfied the having clause. Ok now select the value, ok add 1 to r (@row) and return, r = 4, a = 23.

Comment: So the explanation is: `MySql evaluates r twice once when testing the HAVING expression and once when sending the results to the client`. but the wording in your answer is not right (I'm not selecting r + 1) please correct your answer (and perhaps add above comment to it) and I'll accept it.

Comment: Does that rewording help ? I was using R as it's the row alias (and I typed the answer on my iPad initially) so I apologise for being terse.

Comment: No worries, I'm glad we found a solution!

Answer (score 3):

Accordance to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html

In a SELECT statement, each select expression is evaluated only when sent to the client. This means that in a HAVING, GROUP BY, or ORDER BY clause, referring to a variable that is assigned a value in the select expression list does not work as expected:

```
mysql> SELECT (@aa:=id) AS a, (@aa+3) AS b FROM tbl_name HAVING b=5;
```

The reference to b in the HAVING clause refers to an alias for an expression in the select list that uses @aa. This does not work as expected: @aa contains the value of id from the previous selected row, not from the current row.

So you have data from previous row.

Comment: It seems that this does not apply for `ORDER BY` clause. But I think this is the best answer. +1

Answer (score 2):

I can't explain this behavior (bug?), but here is an alternative solution that works like you would expect HAVING to work:

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT @row := @row + 1 AS r, a FROM test
      JOIN ( SELECT @row := 0 ) AS init
      ORDER BY a) as tmp
WHERE tmp.r = 3
```

Comment: This was my second though, HAVING is for GROUP BY and its likely causing the extra calculation.

Comment: I'm already aware of this, used this alternative to answer [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7119409/mysql-copy-multiple-rows-values-with-same-id-into-new-columns/7119954#7119954).

Answer (score 0):

This looks like bug, but if you'll check implementation of increment in C++ you will see that postfix ++ operation update variable after expression. For stored procedures it can be correct behavior. I think that's the case.